# Automate ssh connection

Tags: python, ssh, terminal, automation, ansible

I’m looking for a tool that help me to automate a ssh connection. This is my task:

```
$ ssh user@server
server: $ dzdo su - superuser
server:superuser: $ //do something
```

As you can see it’s frustrating to do this two or three times a day. I’ve tried with ansible or python but nothing. Somebody knows how can I automate this task, the main problem is get granted permissions. Typing manually no problem but with scripting there’s no way.

Comment: You don't have to run an interactive shell first: `ssh user@server dzdo su - superuser`.

Answer (score 1):

Run `dzdo` as the remote command, instead of the default login shell.

```
$ ssh -t user@server dzdo su - superuser
server:superuser: $ //do something
```

This can be automated with an entry in your `.ssh/config` file:

```
Host serverAlias
  Hostname server
  User user
  RemoteCommand dzdo su - superuser
  RequestTTY yes
```

Then you can run

```
$ ssh serverAlias
```

and `dzdo su - superuser` will run after you connect to `server` as `user`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `expect` library. An example is python [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a key and then configure ssh to use that key along with other options to make things easier. Digital ocean has a good how-to to get going. I haven't done this for awhile but if you look at the man ssh I think the options available are reasonably extensive to meet your needs.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-custom-connection-options-for-your-ssh-client.amp

Answer (score 0):

A script written by me just a second a go, because I needed it for **Jenkins Tomcat Docker SSH configuration automation**. Although it is no problem to run without Docker. Connection from Jenkins to Tomcat. First of all you need to run ssh server on target server (Tomcat)

```
apt-get -y install openssh-server 
service ssh start
```

Since Docker root did not have any password set (*by default it rejects any password until you somehow change it*) **I decided to create new user** for my SSH connection - in future I will transfer files via SSH using this user.

```
useradd --create-home --base-dir /home my_user && echo 'my_user:my_user_password' | chpasswd
```

then for automation purposes on the host (Jenkins)

```
apt-get install -y sshpass
```

Then, in the bash script you see below, I created some variables to store ssh data. During process watch .ssh/ directories on both host and server sides, and watch changes - **this makes you understand**. BTW. all crazy flags are **very likely needed** in order this to work... Go deeper if you wanna know. Any feedback would be appreciated.

**ssh_auth.sh**:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -eu
# tomcat server ssh authentication

SSH_HOST_HOME_DIR='/var/jenkins_home/.ssh'
SSH_SERVER='jenkins_user@tomcat'
SSH_SERVER_AUTH_FILE='/home/jenkins_user/.ssh/authorized_keys'
PRIVATE_KEY='tomcat_key'
if [[ ! -d ${SSH_HOST_HOME_DIR} ]]; then
    mkdir ${SSH_HOST_HOME_DIR}
fi
# clean local .ssh keys - avoid duplicates, scaling etc.
rm -rf ${SSH_HOST_HOME_DIR}/*
cd ${SSH_HOST_HOME_DIR}

# generate ssh pair credentials (xxx.pub - public_key, xxx - PRIVATE_KEY (better not to give it to anyone))
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C 'jenkins' -m PEM -P '' -f ${PRIVATE_KEY}

# authorize jenkins on tomcat server side (this appends jenkins .pub key to tomcat server .ssh/authorized_keys file)
sshpass -e ssh-copy-id -i ${PRIVATE_KEY} -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${SSH_SERVER} # sshpass automates - consider security issues

# clean .ssh keys on server (tomcat) side, execute command via ssh using auth based on PRIVATE_KEY
ssh -i ${PRIVATE_KEY} ${SSH_SERVER} rm -f ${SSH_SERVER_AUTH_FILE}

# authorize single entry .pub key entry on server (tomcat) side
sshpass -e ssh-copy-id -i ${PRIVATE_KEY} -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${SSH_SERVER} # sshpass automates - consider security issues

# ------------------------------------
# connect to tomcat server
# ssh -i tomcat_key jenkins_user@tomcat

# execute a command on tomcat server
# ssh -i tomcat_key jenkins_user@tomcat echo "hello inside tomcat from jenkins"
```